# How to get list of users from microsoft graph who are manage by me

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

**Question:**

How can I list all employee, who are managed by me?

**My Theory**

Everyone can see his manager by:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$expand=manager
or
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/manager
```

So I would request the users api and filter all whose manager attribute is the same like my email.

**What I tried:**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=manager.mail eq 'myemail@company.com';
```

But I get an invalid filter error:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are looking for the [directReports](https://www.michev.info/Blog/Post/3235/reporting-on-manager-and-or-directreports-in-office-365)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/directReports
```

Comment: it looks like that, directReports return the manager to who I report. But I want all users who reports to me. Or am I wrong?

Comment: It should be reverse. I.e. it should return subordinates (it is reverse to "manager"). Just the name is odd, but looks like it should do what you are asking for. Check the link above.

Comment: you are right. its working. thank you a lot